Issue with apt on Ubuntu 24.04: "The package cups-client needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it"
I've been facing a very frustrating issue while trying to install packages on my Ubuntu system through apt. For example I ran:
sudo apt install zotero

However, I got this error:
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

The recommended command doesn't seem to work
sudo dpkg --configure -a


dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-ipp-utils:
 cups-ipp-utils depends on libcups2t64 (= 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.3); however:
  Version of libcups2t64:amd64 on system is 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.2.

...

dpkg: error processing package cups-bsd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

I looked into fixes online and on this website with not luck. Attempts to reinstall cups-client have been unsuccessful:
sudo apt install --reinstall cups-client
E: The package cups-client needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

I even tried purging cups-client, but got this:
sudo apt purge cups-client --autoremove
E: The package cups-client needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

When I tried to force-remove it:
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq cups-client

Error:
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of cups-client:
 printer-driver-splix depends on cups-client.
 cups-bsd depends on cups-client (= 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.3).
 cups depends on cups-client (>= 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.2).

dpkg: error processing package cups-client (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing

I’m now stuck in a loop where I cannot install Zotero or fix the cups-client issue. Has anyone encountered this before, or does anyone have any suggestions for how to resolve this dependency problem?

Please run sudo apt update - that you should do before anything else - and post the full error messages.

You need to add the security updates and noble updates to your /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

then add the following lines:
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates main 
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security main 

Then run:
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install zotero

